# Combining amendsments to database table fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

I am interested to understand the correct approach to solving a database problem I find myself faced with.

I have a table (with ~45 columns) that holds information about stock, it's pricing and a lot of information relating to it's packaging, discounting, etc.

The stock is accessed via a web application using ADO (VB6) by constructing TSQL queries in numerous places.

There is now a need to hold a new table with a very cut down list of the above columns to allow some users to override parts of the stock information from the source (mainly descriptions and such).

The problem I'm faced with is coming up with a way to (perhaps) construct a view of the two tables such that the software still thinks it is talking to the first table (changing the software is simply a no-go) when in fact it is the first table amended by the second, perhaps via some sort of UNION.

To present a simple example, suppose you have a stock table as:

```
CREATE TABLE Stock
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    ref varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    short_description varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    long_description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    ...many other columns
)
```

and an amendments table as:

```
CREATE TABLE StockAmendments
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    ref varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    short_description varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

The idea would be to rename `Stock` as `StockSource` and to build a view called `Stock` which amends `StockSource` with `StockAmendments` (in this case a potentially different `short_description`). This way the software does not need to know about the change.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to change the data in the original table or just in the 'view'?

Comment: Just the view, the source and amendment table need to remain intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable.  I haven't done t-sql in a very long time but something like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW Stock 
AS
SELECT 
  ss.id, 
  ss.ref, 
  iif(isnull(sa.short_description), ss.short_description, sa.short_description)) as short_description, 
  ss.long_description
FROM StockSource ss, StockAmendments sa
WHERE ss.id = sa.id AND ss.ref = sa.ref
```

One thing to worry about is query performance depending on indexes, etc.  If this is a problem, you might be better off creating a real 'Stock' table based off of StockSource and putting a trigger on StockAmendments to update the 'Stock' table.

Comment: What if there are no amendments to a row, would I be right that your query would simply not include the source item either?

Comment: `iif` is not available prior to sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using updatable views.

Rename Stock as StockSource and to build an updatable view Stock over StockSource and StockAmendments. This way you'll not have to do any change in VB6 code.